# How do I change my online Smash Tag name?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

How do I change the player name shown on my Smash Tag when playing online in Super Smash Bros. Ultimate?

I can change my tag’s icon and color in the online options, but I don’t see an option for my display name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your online Smash Tag name is based on your user profile's nickname in the Switch’s system settings.

To change your nickname, go to the home menu and open System Settings. Scroll down to "Users" and select your profile. Select the "Nickname" option to pick a new name.

**Note**: If you change nicknames while Smash Bros is open, your new name will be applied after closing and relaunching the game.